# Determine if this Linear Transformation is 1-1 and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $\{\mathbb{v}_1, \mathbb{v}_2\}$ be a basis for the vector space $V$, and suppose that $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation. If $T(\mathbb{v}_1)=\mathbb{v_1}+2\mathbb{v_2}$ and $T(\mathbb{v}_2)=2\mathbb{v_1}-3\mathbb{v_2}$, determine whether $T$ is one-to-one, onto, both, or neither. Find $T^{-1}$ or explain why it does not exist.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Write out the matrix for $T$ and use what you know about LinAlg.

Comment: Instead of saying "how would I go about it", you should explain what you know or what you've tried first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ Lovsovs, start with the matrix form
$$
\mathbf{T} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The reduced row echelon form is
$$
 \mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{T}} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Can you apply your definitions of $1-1$ and onto now?

$$
\mathbf{T}^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 -3 & 2 \\
 2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the help.